# Read XML using Linq without element names

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to read an XML file, I'm trying to use Linq but I'm having some issues getting to the descendants. I need to be able to get the desendants without knowing the element names. Is this possible?

Here is the XML:

```
<Root>
        <myResponse>
            <GUID></GUID>
            <TType code="1">myTType Value
                <TSubType tc="1">TSubType Value</TSubType>
            </TType>    
            <TDate>1999-09-19</TDate>
            <TTime>16:00:00.0Z</TTime>
        </myResponse>
    </Root>
```

Here is my code:

```
using (XmlReader nodeReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Projects\GetXML\Test2.xml"))

                 {
                     nodeReader.MoveToContent();

                XDocument xRoot = XDocument.Load(nodeReader, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);


            foreach (XElement e in xRoot.Elements("Root").DescendantsAndSelf())
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}",
                    ("".PadRight(e.Ancestors().Count() * 2) + e.Name).PadRight(20), " = " ,
                    (e.Value).PadRight(5));


                }
```

My results:

```
Root                 = 


        myTType Value
            TSubType Value

        1999-09-19
        16:00:00.0Z


  myResponse         = 

        myTType Value
            TSubType Value

        1999-09-19
        16:00:00.0Z

    GUID             =      
    TType            = myTType Value
            TSubType Value

      TSubType       = TSubType Value
    TDate            = 1999-09-19
    TTime            = 16:00:00.0Z
```

What I am expecting:

```
Root                 = 
        myResponse         = 

                GUID             =      
                TType            = myTType Value    
                  TSubType       = TSubType Value
                TDate            = 1999-09-19
                TTime            = 16:00:00.0Z
```

Comment: The title and description are very different from what your actual/expected shows. You *are* getting elements without knowing their names in advance already, you're just not getting empty elements, formatting the results correctly, etc.

Comment: As a side note, that may be the most poorly indented code I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `e.Value`, try using:

`string.Concat(e.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value))`.

You could also use:

`e.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault().Value`

but then you risk not getting all of the text (if it is split). For example:

```
<Root>
  <myResponse>
            <GUID></GUID>
            <TType code="1">myTType Value
                <TSubType tc="1">TSubType Value</TSubType>
               Some more text
            </TType>    
            <TDate>1999-09-19</TDate>
            <TTime>16:00:00.0Z</TTime>
        </myResponse>
    </Root>
```

With this XML the first piece of code will also include "Some more text", and the second piece won't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get the formatted result similar to what you are expecting.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("xmlfile1.xml");
var allNodes = root.DescendantNodesAndSelf();
int maxNameLength = allNodes.OfType<XElement>()
    .Select(x => x.Name.LocalName.Length)
    .Max();
foreach (XNode x in allNodes)
{
    XElement node = x as XElement;
    if (node != null)
    {
        int numAncestors = node.Ancestors().Count();

        XText textNode = node.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
        string text = "";
        if (textNode != null)
            text = textNode.Value.Trim();

        string name = node.Name.LocalName;
        // PadLeft() subtracts the string.Length from the padding
        // so add its length to the padding amount
        string left = name.PadLeft(numAncestors * 5 + name.Length);
        // PadRight() wasn't giving the expected results 
        // so improvised with the following
        string right = left + "".PadLeft(maxNameLength + 5 - name.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", right, text);
    }
}
```

With the result:

```
Root            = 
     myResponse      = 
          GUID            = 
          TType           = myTType Value
               TSubType        = TSubType Value
          TDate           = 1999-09-19
          TTime           = 16:00:00.0Z
```

Edited to calculate the max name length of all the names, in-case you have a bigger file to run this against and have some really long names.